# Where clause searches everything if it has character `s` at the end

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to run a simple `select` command in `sqlite3` and getting strange result.  I want to search a column and display all rows that has a string `dockerhosts` in it.  But result shows rows without `dockerhosts` string in it.

For example search for `dockerhosts`:

```
sqlite> SELECT command FROM history WHERE command like '%dockerhosts%' ORDER BY id DESC limit 50;
git status
git add --all v1 v2
git status
```

If I remove `s` from the end I get what I need:

```
sqlite> SELECT command FROM history WHERE command like '%dockerhost%' ORDER BY id DESC limit 50;
git checkout -b hotfix/collapse-else-if-in-dockerhost
vi opt/dockerhosts/Docker
aws s3 cp dockerhosts.json s3://xxxxx/dockerhosts.json --profile dev
aws s3 cp dockerhosts.json s3://xxxxx/dockerhosts.json --profile dev
history | grep dockerhost | grep prod
history | grep dockerhosts.json
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I see a note here that there are configurable limits for a LIKE pattern - https://sqlite.org/limits.html ... 10 seems pretty short but maybe that's what you are running into.

Comment: Hehe =) @JenR that's the answer, thanks a lot,  tried with `limit 49` - works fine.   set to `50` and got wrong result.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a note here that there are configurable limits for a LIKE pattern - [sqlite.org/limits.html](http://sqlite.org/limits.html) ... 10 seems pretty short but maybe that's what you are running into.

> The pattern matching algorithm used in the default LIKE and GLOB
>   implementation of SQLite can exhibit O(N²) performance (where N is the
>   number of characters in the pattern) for certain pathological cases.
>   To avoid denial-of-service attacks from miscreants who are able to
>   specify their own LIKE or GLOB patterns, the length of the LIKE or
>   GLOB pattern is limited to SQLITE_MAX_LIKE_PATTERN_LENGTH bytes. The
>   default value of this limit is 50000. A modern workstation can
>   evaluate even a pathological LIKE or GLOB pattern of 50000 bytes
>   relatively quickly. The denial of service problem only comes into play
>   when the pattern length gets into millions of bytes. Nevertheless,
>   since most useful LIKE or GLOB patterns are at most a few dozen bytes
>   in length, paranoid application developers may want to reduce this
>   parameter to something in the range of a few hundred if they know that
>   external users are able to generate arbitrary patterns.
>
> The maximum length of a LIKE or GLOB pattern can be lowered at
>   run-time using the
>   sqlite3_limit(db,SQLITE_LIMIT_LIKE_PATTERN_LENGTH,size) interface.